# NodeList.length is always returning 0

Tags: javascript, nodelist

I have a NodeList object that is created by

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByName("signupButton");

console.log(buttons);
```

prints

```
[item: function]
0: button.btn.btn-warning.btn-lg
1: button.btn.btn-warning.btn-lg
2: button.btn.btn-warning.btn-lg
length: 3
__proto__: NodeList
```

But buttons.length is printing 0. What is going on here?

Comment: Can you post a complete code example please?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8bm1HvNA

Comment: Your code is running at the top of the page, which means that the elements don't exist when it runs. You solve this by moving your script to the bottom of the page, or by putting your code in a callback function that runs after the document is loaded.

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because the DOM has not loaded yet when your JS is executing. The reason its showing up in the console is because chrome, or maybe firefox, will update the console when the DOM changes, essentially changing the output in the console.

In order for this to work, you have two options:

- register an event handler for when the DOM is loaded and execute this
  code then.

  `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    // the code
    //make AJAX request when button is clicked
    var buttons = document.getElementsByName("signupButton");
  });`
- move this script tag right before the closing  tag to ensure the DOM will have loaded when it gets executed.

  `</body>
  <script>
    // the code
  </script>`