# nodelist.length returns 0 with code inside script

Tags: javascript

Today I ran into a spontaneously generated, random issue. I must have done something to generate it, a browser update, or something. Anyway, I have a list of checkboxes in my html, all under the name of checkered. (The post.id is using angular, in case anyone is wondering.)

```
<input type="checkbox" id="post.id" name="checkered">
```

Anyways, I'm importing a script at the top that holds a function called "summarize".

```
<script src="../scripts/post/controller_post.js"></script>
```

I am calling this function when a button is pressed (meaning the DOM *should be loaded*).

```
// Makes a summary
function summarize(postID){
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkered');
    console.log(checkboxes);
    console.log(checkboxes.length);

    for(var i=0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) 
    {
        if(checkboxes[i].checked)
        {//do stuff
        }
    }
};
```

EDIT

Context: I'm using angular with bootstrap modals to create posts, while checkboxes on the page determine whether a post is a summary of one or more of the other posts.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="savePostModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myPostLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form name="form" role="form" novalidate class="ng-scope ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-dirty ng-valid-minlength" ng-submit="createMob()">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="clear()">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myPostLabel">Create or edit a Post</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>ID</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" ng-model="post.id" readonly>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Title</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="test" placeholder="Title your post..." ng-model="post.name" ng-minlength=1 required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Author</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="test" placeholder="Temporary Field..." ng-model="post.author" ng-minlength=1 required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Text</label>
                        <textarea rows="8" placeholder="Status update here..." class="form-control" type="text" name="test" ng-model="post.text" ng-minlength=1 required></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="clear()">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span> Cancel
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" ng-click="closeModal()" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Save
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Once it calls the create function, the create makes a post.

```
$scope.create = function () {
    // populate summary field
    $scope.post.summary = isSummary();
    Post.save($scope.post, function () {
        $('#savePostModal').modal('hide');
        $scope.posts = Post.query();
        $scope.clear();
        $scope.posts.$promise.then(function(data) 
        {
            summarize(data[data.length - 1].id);
            postData = data;
        });
    });
};
```

The create function calls the summarize function with the id number of a post. Inside this function we see that I get elements from the page the script is running on named "checkered" and this is where the problem kicks in.

The nodelist is being logged fine and dandy, but when I try to get the length it returns 0, almost as if the elements on the page haven't been loaded yet, such as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894000/nodelist-length-is-always-returning-0), but as far I can tell, they should be. Thoughts?

Comment: Set up a Fiddle, so we can see the behavior.

Comment: You should be able to load the page and then just type `document.getElementsByName("checkered")` at the console prompt. If it returns an empty list, then that means the page doesn't contain the markup that you think it does, and you should explore the DOM (also with the developer tools) to see what it actually looks like.

Comment: @Pointy, I tried what you suggested and it returned "[<input type=​"checkbox" id=​"post.id" name=​"checkered">​, <input type=​"checkbox" id=​"post.id" name=​"checkered">...]" so that appears to be working.

Comment: If you're creating the elements in response to a server request, then it would seem that you're not waiting for the server response before fetching the elements.

Comment: @BuiltInParris so if you click the button *after* you've done that manual verification, does it still fail? Is there a second window involved somehow?

Comment: Also whether or not the script is imported from a script file or is inline almost certainly has nothing whatsoever to do with the problem.

Comment: sixfingeredman, I'm not creating them with a server request, merely trying to access them with some client side javascript that takes place post-loading. It's weird because I'm thus far unable to duplicate the problem with a jsfiddle, though I have been trying. @Pointy, clicking the button after manual verification still causes failure. I am using a modal window overlayed on the page, but I tried running the script in between each interval of the process (including with the window open), and it returns the right result in the console while the function still fails. I'll post more context code.

Comment: I realized that comment was a little ambiguous. The code posted directly in the console gives me the right result, while the code in my script is continuing to give me 0.

Comment: Well if your "modal window" is an `<iframe>` or a separate window, then there are **two** `document` objects involved, and the code has to be referring to the proper one.

Comment: No, @Pointy see the code I added in the original post.

Comment: Reduce your code while keeping the problem: most of the code you've listed isn't relevant to the behaviour you see behind exhibited. Simply copy your entire project dir, and start weeding in your files: remove all checkboxes but one. Does summarize load at all? How it's loaded is clearly not relevant to the problem you're seeing. When you get the nodelist, does it have a length and data before you do anything with it? At this point your code should be small enough to turn into a jsbin.com example - do so, and then update your question with precision data. Everyone wins.

Comment: I'm doing my best Mike, I've been eliminating and I have a previous version that was working, which I'm working on getting active again as I type. I added the additional code only after I thought it became useful for people to know the context. Every fiddle I've made online works though, which is why I haven't been able to create an example.

Comment: I tried an older version, and for some reason, that one is having the same issue now. Bizarre. I realized a relevant detail is that I'm using AngularJS and the checkboxes are inside of an ng-repeat, so they are being populated via Angular... Not that it should matter, I think, since they are already loaded by the time the function is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, contrary to Mike's statement about the code I posted not being related, it turns out that the answer was in the code I added to the revised post. The issue here was that I was using AngularJS with an ng-repeat statement to create checkboxes and, for whatever reason, when I called the summarized function inside of the function

```
$scope.posts.$promise.then(function(data){ //stuff}
```

the code was no longer able to access the document. I don't understand AngularJS well enough to understand why this is true, but I do know it be the root of the problem as I assigned the data from the promise statement to a temporary value and executed the summarize function outside of that statement and it worked flawlessly.  However, I do have to give a big thanks to @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans anyway because without his reminder to break my error into smaller pieces, I wouldn't have found the issue nearly as quickly. Hopefully other AngularJS users who encounter this issue can benefit from my issue.